# How can I express a Constructor Function with static variables in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, types

I have the following class that I would like to access in a different file:

```
export class Person {

    constructor() {}

    static getDatabaseId(): string {
        return '...';
    }
}
```

**It's injected and not actually imported.** I want to make clear that it is a constructor function and that it can create new instances of type *Person*. This is what I tried:

```
let PersonConstructor: {new(): Person};

// inject Person constructor function
beforeEach(inject((_Person_) => {
    PersonConstructor = _Person_;
}));

// create a new instance but also access the static variables
const p: Person = new PersonConstructor();
PersonConstructor.getDatabaseId(); // "property does not exist"
```

The compiler doesn't complain about instantiating new instances from *Person* anymore but of course it also doesn't know of *Person*'s static variables now since they are missing on the newly declared type.

How can this be typed correctly?

Comment: what is "const Person: {new(): Person)" for?

Comment: I renamed it so It's clearer: PersonConstructor is a constructor function that creates instances of type Person.

Comment: An instance member belongs to the class not the object, which means that whenever you create a new instance of Person it won't have static members, in this case `getDatabaseId()` method.

Comment: I updated my code example: The constructor function is injected and assigned to a local variable. So I have to express somehow what is getting injected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the constructor signature method but you will need to add any other members you need to access.

```
import {Person} from './Person';

let PersonConstructor: {
    new(): Person
    getDatabaseId(): string
} = Person;

// create a new instance but also access the static variables
const p: Person = new PersonConstructor();
PersonConstructor.getDatabaseId(); // "property does not exist"
```

Alternately, you could just use `typeof Person` if you want to use the exact same  type as the `Person` (constructor signature and all statics):

```
import {Person} from './Person';

let PersonConstructor: typeof Person = Person;

// create a new instance but also access the static variables
const p: Person = new PersonConstructor();
PersonConstructor.getDatabaseId(); // "property does not exist"
```

Comment: The second code example was what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what is the final goal of your code. As of [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) doc one possible usage of syntax you tring to achive is to modify `static` member of the class and create new instances with new static members.

If you are going to do that correct code will look like

```
let PersonConstructor: typeof Person = Person;

// create a new instance but also access the static variables
const p: Person = new PersonConstructor();
PersonConstructor.getDatabaseId(); // Also OK and you my change it. Original Person will not get it changed.
```